# How can I use FileChooserNative from PyGTK3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygtk, gtk3

GTK3 includes `FileChooserNative`: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-GtkFileChooserNative.html

I'm developing a simple application using the GTK3 Python bindings and I thought it would be nice to use a native file chooser but I can't figure out how to use it:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>> gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango, GLib
>>> foo = Gtk.FileChooserNative
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 139, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'FileChooserNative'
```

The GTK3 Python bindings generally follow the documented C interface pretty closely but there is very little other API documentation (at least that I've found). Can I not use the `FileChooserNative` from the Python interface or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-GtkFileChooserNative.html#gtk-file-chooser-native-new says since Gtk3.20. You have 3.20 or later, right?

Comment: D'oh... I'm using Gtk 3.22 on Windows but Gtk 3.18 on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.